# How can a registers-only instruction stall due to "memory dependencies"?

Tags: cuda, nvprof, nvvp

I am profiling CUDA kernel using nvprof with PC sampling enabled, as to understand some latency problems I am having. The GPU I am using is the P100 (compute 6.0)

PC sampling reports that a DFMA is stalling frequently due to memory dependencies. The SASS code for the DFMA is as follows:

```
 DFMA R22, R4, R8, R22
```

My take of the problem is that R8 needs to be loaded via an LDG.E.CI.64 with a very high miss rate on L2.

The definition of a memory dependency stall is "A load/store cannot be made because the required resources are not available or are fully utilized, or too many requests of a given type are outstanding."

What confuses me is that DFMA are not load/store operations and if I am right that the stall is due to data not available on R8, then it should be an execution dependency. What does a memory dependency stall on a DFMA means?

Comment: The definition you cite seems misleading to me. What you describe indeed matches perfectly my experience of memory dependencies in nvvp. If these where shown as execution dependencies, there would be no way of identifying memory dependency stalls because they would all match the definition of an execution dependency.

Comment: But then what would be an execution dependency if not registers used for input not yet filled up?

Comment: Anything that doesn't originate from memory. E.g. if you have two DFMA instructions back-to-back, with the second using the output of the first as an input.